# MySql create user - can't connect using valid credentials

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create new user in mysql and give him privileges to mess with one table.

Commands I've used:

```
CREATE USER 'integration'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'integration1';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, ALTER, UPDATE, CREATE, DROP ON testdb.testtable TO 'integration'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But unfortunately I can't connect to database using right credentials:

```
mysql.exe -uintegration -pintegration1 testdb
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your environment? What program are you using to connect to MySQL?

Comment: What exactly is the message you're getting?

Comment: Here is error message
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'integration'@'localhost' using password: YES)`

Comment: `
    Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
    Software: MySQL
    Software version: 5.5.27-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
    Protocol version: 10
    User: root@localhost
    Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)`
I'm using command line client provided with mysql installer.

Comment: `mysql.exe -u integration -pintegration1 testdb`, there's a space after the `u` (not after the `p`)

Comment: there's no need to left an space @Sebas

Comment: @J33nn you'd better start with operating system. It is possible to notice that you use mysql. **exe** , so it's Windows, but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that MySQL has its specific way of handling the host from where connection originates. Generally `localhost` doesn't fall under `'%'`. Try connecting using this command:

```
mysql.exe -uintegration -pintegration1 -h127.0.0.1 testdb
```

This will initiate a connection from user `'integration'@'127.0.0.1'` instead of `'integration'@'localhost'`

Comment: So you are saying that in order to allow connecting to database for both any host and localhost I need to create 2 different users? Anyway: `mysql.exe -u integration -pintegration1 -h127.0.0.1 iwork
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user integration'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Yes. Based on experience, localhost is not included in '%'.

Comment: @J33nn Yes, you do need to create 2 different users. And they could have different priveleges. I didn't try this solution, you probably could check on mysql.exe command line reference. Or you could create a user `'integration'@'localhost'` and give this user same priveleges. But take note that if you update priveleges for one of them you should also manually update the other's.

Comment: But I can't create such account:

`mysql> CREATE USER 'integration'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'integration1';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'integration'@'localhost'`

Comment: @J33nn could you post results of this query: `select user,host from mysql.user;`? You would probably need to connect to MySQL as `root`. Either here or update the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect locally, you must add the user @localhost.

```
CREATE USER 'integration'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'integration1';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, ALTER, UPDATE, CREATE, DROP ON testdb.testtable TO 'integration'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: But I want to allow all hosts to connect to my database not only connection from localhost.

Comment: You can do it twice with everything identical except once for localhost, once for '%'. Just make sure if you change the password on one, you do it for both.